# Use MapWhen with multiple file extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to check for multiple file extensions when using the MapWhen in my Startup.cs inside an ASP.NET Core project? I currently have this code, but can't figure out how to make this a bit more 'intelligent' maybe?

```
app.MapWhen(context =>
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".png") ||
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".pdf") ||
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".xlsx") ||
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".xlsb") ||
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".xlsm") ||
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".docx") ||
   context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".doc"),
   appBranch =>
   {
      appBranch.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
```

Not sure if I can do a check for multiple file extensions at once?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
app.MapWhen(context =>
    //Load below array from config if you wish to. 
    var supportedExtensions = new string[] { ".png", ".pdf", ".xlsx" };
    var dotIndex = context.Request.Path.ToString().IndexOf('.');
    if(dotIndex == -1) return false;
    var pathExtn = context.Request.Path.ToString().Substring(dotIndex);
    return supportedExtensions.Contains(pathExtn);
appBranch =>
{
  appBranch.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
```

Comment: No problem. You can clean it up quite a bit more if you use `Path.GetExtension`, also. Obviously that's up to you, as what you have is a working solution.